# Measuring a duration with microtime results randomly in zero

Tags: php, duration, microtime

I am having a loop like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '16024M');
ini_set('set_time_limit', 9999);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 9999);
ini_set('display_errors',  TRUE);
ini_set('error_reporting',  E_ALL);

for ($k = 1; $k <= 50; $k++) {

    $haystack = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {

        $randomChar = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26), 1);

        $haystack[] = $randomChar;

    }

    $haystack[] = 'X';

    $startTime = microtime(true);

    // sleep(0);

    $result = in_array('X', $haystack);

    $endTime = microtime(true);

    echo number_format(1000000 * ($endTime - $startTime), 20, ",", " ") . ' ';

 }
```

And these are the first couple of lines from the output:

> 1,90734863281250000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 1,19209289550781250000
> 1,90734863281250000000
> 1,19209289550781250000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 1,90734863281250000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 20,02716064453125000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 1,19209289550781250000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 0,00000000000000000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 0,00000000000000000000
> 0,95367431640625000000
> 0,00000000000000000000

As you can see, there are a couple of lines stating a duration of "0" - which is in fact not possible. If I uncomment the line containing the **sleep(0)** command, there is no zero-duration.

### System-Setup

- PHP 7.0 with FPM
- nginx 1.10.3
- Ubuntu 16.04

I am running the loop on the CLI and calling it via the Browser.

Comment: Are you running your webserver on windows?

Comment: No, it's running on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Turn `error_reporting` up to max, and make sure that `display errors` is on.

Comment: error_reporting et. al. is activated, added this to the code

Comment: Weird. 3v4l shows the same behaviour in all versions of PHP7. https://3v4l.org/oL6RI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

101 items in array is small enough for smart php with it's [static optimization](https://www.slideshare.net/nikita_ppv/static-optimization-of-php-bytecode-phpsc-2017) tricks and powerful cpu.

If You want to see that 0-s are gone, so generate 1000 items:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $haystack[] = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26), 1);
}
```

P.S. I've checked Your code using both 7.1 and 5.6 so there are big differences:

[image: php7.1 vs php5.6]

Comment: Thanks for that. That was just a part of my complete script, in fact I am using much bigger numbers, see the full script here: https://gist.github.com/nickyreinert/fb7d195db011287730f9c6a1ab7885a5

Comment: @n.r. I've executed Your script on 7.1 php I did not get zeroes, I've waited a bit also - no zeroes

Comment: OK, I now get what you mean. Actually, I did the same, running the script with an array of 100.000 keys. I was wondering, why there are 0 durations for smaller arrays. So - "Static Optimization" is the final explanation?

Comment: I think yes, slides: https://www.slideshare.net/nikita_ppv/static-optimization-of-php-bytecode-phpsc-2017 and pdf explains what improvements they have done: http://biagiocosenza.com/papers/PopovCC17.pdf

Comment: But then I still wonder about two things: Why are the other loops not affected and why will a simple sleep(0) affect this behavior in a negative way? I will look into it... thanks anyways!

Comment: And third: As I am measuring in Microseconds, this means, the result will come in an incredible short amount of almost no time.

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to @num8er answer, which seems to be THE answer, I tried to find out more, because this really caused me some sleepless nights. I improved the above script a bit and ran some additional measurements:

```
  ini_set('memory_limit', '16024M');
  ini_set('set_time_limit', 9999);
  ini_set('set_time_limit', -1);
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 9999);
  ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
  ini_set('display_errors',  TRUE);
  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>duration</th>";
    echo "<th>position</th>";
    echo "<th>fake</th>";
    echo "<th>found</th>";
    echo "<th>optimized</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$endPosition = TRUE;

$fake = false;

for ($k = 1; $k <= 10000; $k++) {

    $haystack = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 50000; $i++) {

        $randomChar = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26), 1);

        $haystack[] = $randomChar;

    }

    if ($fake) {

        $needle = NULL;


    } else {

        if ($endPosition) {

            $needle = $haystack[sizeof($haystack) - 1];

        } else {

            $needle = $haystack[floor(sizeof($haystack)/ 2)];

        }

    }

    $startTime = microtime(true);

    //sleep(0);

    $result = in_array($needle, $haystack);

    $endTime = microtime(true);

    $duration = ($endTime - $startTime);

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo number_format($duration, 30, ",", " ");
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo ($endPosition) ? "end": "middle";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo ($fake) ? "fake": "no fake";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo ($result) ? "found": "not found";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo ($duration == 0) ? "optimized": "---";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $endPosition = (rand(0,100) < 50) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $fake = (rand(0,100) < 25) ? TRUE : FALSE;

}

echo "</table>";
```

I added a random "fake feature". Randomly 25% of the iterations should not return a positive search result. And in random 50% of the iterations, the needle will be placed in the middle of the haystack and not at the end. 
I ran this script a couple of times for different settings (**iterations**, **array length**) and at the end I had around 225.000 result rows. Quickly adding a little pivot table shows, where PHP (7.0.32 fpm and the CPU (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz) reaching a limit:

[image: minimum durations when searching arrays, lengths vs iterations]

Numbers are milliseconds / 1000, so even the hard ones (like 500.000 keys, 1.000 iterations) took 0,000000953674 Microseconds - thanks to the optimization. That's impressive.

What also is interesting: The minimum durations, if not "0", are the same (**0,000953674**) or **doubled** (**0,000001907349**), even for different iterations! So, my assumption is, but that's pretty naive thinking, if I would run a test with bigger arrays or more iterations, the next upcoming minium would be **0.00000381469 microseonds**.

As you also can see, and as num8er already stated out, the potential for optimization grows the harder the job is.

[image: Top 10 of quickest durations for 50.000-key-arrays]

10 times crawling arrays with a length of 50.000 keys is even slower then 100 or 1.000 iterations. Of 1.000 iterations more than 10% are of the results were delivered in the "optimized" time.

Finally, I want to point out, that there seems to be no difference, if the **needle** is in the middle of the haystack, or at the end. Next chart shows the minium durations for 10, 100 and 1.000 iterations when searching a 500.000 key array. As you can see, the minium is always the "magical" 0,000000953674:

[image: Minimum durations for 500.000-key-arrays with different needle positions]

Needless to say, that every iteration returns the correct result. So, **in_array()** never returned a positive result, when it crawled the haystack-array containing no needle.

That may does not add deeper technical details to the PHP-optimization feature, but yet I guess it's interesting to see the impact of this feature.